# lost with obj-c weak link etc

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am new to this and have no clue, i've read quite some things now, but somehow they all seem to miss explaining this.

I'm working on a game thingy to get into it, but somehow I get lost with this.

GameScene.h has a the following declarations in theinterface:

```
Player *player; 
b2Body *b2PlayerBody;
```

inside the GameScene.mm (using box2d, so need .mm) when in a function i create the player (which comes from another class) I set this b2PlayerBody to the body i've used, to push it to the player class and work with it.

```
-(void) addPlayerAtPosition:(CGPoint)p
{
    CCLOG(@"Adding player at %0.2f x %02.f",p.x,p.y);

    // Player
    player = [[Player alloc] initWithPosition:ccp(p.x, p.y)];
    player.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0.5);
    [self addChild:player z:10 tag:kTagPlayerNode];



    // Define the dynamic body.
    //Set up a 1m squared box in the physics world
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(p.x/PTM_RATIO, p.y/PTM_RATIO);
    b2PlayerBody = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    b2PlayerBody->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
    [player setPhysicsBody:b2PlayerBody];
}
```

In my Update method of this file I call (dt is delta):

```
[player update:dt withBody:b2PlayerBody]; //update player
```

In the player.h file i have:
a declatration for

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt withBody:(b2Body *)body;
```

and inside the player.mm file i have

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt withBody:(b2Body *)body {

}
```

When starting, it crashes on the update from GameScene.mm without any error text

```
[player update:dt withBody:b2PlayerBody]; //update player
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also can someone epxlain to me what the difference is (sorry if this is a stupid q) between

b2Body* b2PlayerBody;
b2Body *b2PlayerBody; // i know this is a weak link, but what's the diff.
b2Body b2PlayerBody;

also do these link methods have effect on memory release in the release method?

Comment: i've solved it by (b2Body *)body { in the method and (b2body*) in the init... still like to know though...

Answer (score -1):

```
b2Body * b2PlayerBody;
b2Body* b2PlayerBody;
b2Body *b2PlayerBody;
```

Instance variables (pointers in this case) with no memory management keywords (respectively the "assign" property) are called "weak references". The placement of the asterisk makes no difference and is purely a consideration of which style you prefer. Personally, I prefer the asterisk next to the data type, not the variable.

Weak linking only refers to static libraries, ie you can "weak link" to Game Center so that your app runs on devices without Game Center. In that case you must make sure the app doesn't call any GC methods on devices without GC.

These declarations have no effect on memory management. You're responsible for allocating and releasing the instance variables as necessary. In this case it is done through the Box2D API, ie via CreateBody and DestroyBody methods.

Comment: With ARC, instance variables are NOT weak references, they default to `__strong` references. This could be very confusing to someone learning ARC in the future, and getting confused between `__weak` and `weak linking`. So I down vote as this question doesn't have enough clarity for my tastes.